# System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not load assembly System.Configuration Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, .net-standard

I have the following error:

[image]

It only happens on android, in ios everything is fine.

The error appears only when I refer a pcl to my pcl in xamarin forms.

My PCL in Xamarin Forms:
[image]

My PCL:
[image]

I read:

[Add a reference to a class library which target .NET standard 2.0 to a Xamarin PCL which targets .NET Standard 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362801/add-a-reference-to-a-class-library-which-target-net-standard-2-0-to-a-xamarin-p?rq=1)

https://mallibone.com/post/using-pcl-only-libraries-with-net-standard
https://montemagno.com/installing-a-pcl-into-netstandard-libraries/

Comment: why do you try to use 2 PCL? Use only the .net standard 2.0 one.

Comment: I need to share code between different projects that are not .net standard 2.0. Only a class, in my pcl I do not install any Nuget

Comment: You cannot use .net framework 4.7.1 on your android app. You must check here [.NET Standard implementation support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) to make sure that the android app meets the requirements.

Comment: copy the old code to the .net std 2.0 project

Answer (score 0):

> The error appears only when I refer a pcl to my pcl in xamarin forms.

You are referencing a .Net 4.7.1 PCL in a .Net Standard 2.0 PCL, Which are not 100% compatible with each other. And from your error message, you are using `System.Configuration.CertainClass` in your .Net PCL which doesn't exists in .Net Standards.

So, what you need to do is create a .Net Standard 2.0 PCL instead and reference it in your PCL, copy all your codes and try to clear the not-compatible part.

You can find .Net Standard PCL under `File->New->Project-.Net Standard->Class Library(.Net Standard)`.